# Python3 deepcopy class instance doesn't work

Tags: python, deep-copy

I created 2 class instances(stack0, stack1) from a class Stack
There is a class variable named  in class Stack, which has the other stack address(reference), ie) stack0.other_stack is stack1 and stack1.other_stack is stack0.
but It doesn't work as I expected though I used deepcopy function.

I tried making a class function that deepcopies the other_stack.

```
stack0 = Stack(stack_list, arr_size//2, 0)
stack1 = Stack(stack_list, arr_size//2, 1)
stack0.other_stack = deepcopy(stack1)
stack1.other_stack = deepcopy(stack0)
print(stack0.other_stack is stack1)
print(id(stack0.other_stack), id(stack1))
```

`print(stack0.other_stack is stack1)` prints: `False`

`print(id(stack0.other_stack), id(stack1))` prints: `4328836344 4328835224`

I expected `stack0.other_stack` is the exactly same as `stack1` and vice-versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `is` keyword checks if the identity of two values is the same, which is implemented through the memory address. Making a (deep)copy will create a copy in a new memory address, which is why `stack1 is deepcopy(stack1)` returns `False`.

Comment: so how can I make them have same memory address? I want to modify different stack in other stack's class function.

Comment: To achieve this you can assign the `other_stack` as `stack0.other_stack = stack1`. This will copy `stack1` by reference, so `stack0.other_stack` will point to `stack1`.